# spring generic application event failing to reach destination

Tags: java, spring

i have the following spring holder bean. the idea is it retains an instance of something and fires a change event when that something changes (supplying both the old and new values):

```
public class Holder<T> implements ApplicationEventPublisherAware {
    private final Class<T> payloadType; //because java generics are incomplete
    private T curr; //latest value being held
    private ApplicationEventPublisher publisher; //spring context ref

    public Holder(Class<T> payloadType) {
        this.payloadType = payloadType;
    }

    public void change() throws Exception {
        T prev = curr;
        curr = payloadType.newInstance();
        publisher.publishEvent(new ContentsChangedEvent<>(prev, curr));
    }
}
```

and then i have a listener class that reacts to those events:

```
@Named
public class Listener {

    @EventListener
    public void onChange(ContentsChangedEvent<Cat> event) {
        //never gets called
    }

    @EventListener
    public void onErasedChange(ContentsChangedEvent<?> event) {
        //does get called
    }
}
```

my issue is that the generic (correct) event listener method never gets invoked (the one that gets `Event<Cat>`), only the erased one.

for completeness' sake, here is the spring context.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="net.radai"/>

    <bean id="holder" class="net.radai.Holder">
        <constructor-arg type="java.lang.Class" value="net.radai.Cat"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I've also put the whole thing on github - https://github.com/radai-rosenblatt/spring-events. its a maven project - you build it and you'll get a failing test.

what am i doing wrong?

**NOTE:** in the real use case for this i expect to have multiple such Holders and forcing all listeners to discard events not relevant to them in unacceptable

Comment: Spring is converting the event as "PayloadApplicationEvent<Object>" and as a result calling the wildcard listener method.

Comment: `public class ContentsChangedEvent<T> extends ApplicationEvent{     public ContentsChangedEvent(Holder<T> source, T prev, T curr) {
     super(source);
     this.prev = prev;
        this.curr = curr;
    }                                  
} 
//Holder class
public void change() {
        T prev = curr;
        try {
        curr = payloadType.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            int g = 8;
        }
        publisher.publishEvent(new ContentsChangedEvent<T>(this, prev, curr));
 }`
Both onChange and onErasedChange will be invoked. Do you need the wildcard listener method?

Comment: @Sanj - no, i do not need the wildcard listener. thank you - your solution works. if you could phrase it as an answer i could close this question :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class ContentsChangedEvent<T> extends ApplicationEvent{

    public ContentsChangedEvent(Holder<T> source, T prev, T curr) {
        super(source);
        this.prev = prev;
        this.curr = curr;
    }                                  

}   

//Holder class
public void change() {
        T prev = curr;
        try {
        curr = payloadType.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            int g = 8;
        }
        publisher.publishEvent(new ContentsChangedEvent<T>(this, prev, curr));
 }
```

Both onChange and onErasedChange will be invoked.

Comment: or, as an alternative a small fix to spring would let me avoid extending ApplicationEvent - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/pull/994

Answer (score 11):

If you implement org.springframework.core.ResolvableTypeProvider in your generic event class, then listener will resolve it.
As an example:

```
import org.springframework.core.ResolvableType;
import org.springframework.core.ResolvableTypeProvider;

public class EventBase<T> {
    public T payload;
}

public class AppEvent<T> extends EventBase<T> implements ResolvableTypeProvider {
    @Override
    public ResolvableType getResolvableType() {
        return ResolvableType.forClassWithGenerics(
            getClass(), 
            ResolvableType.forInstance(this.payload)
        );
    }
}

@Component
public class EventHandler {
    @EventListener
    public void handleString(AppEvent<String> event) {
       System.out.println("Event[" + event.getClass().getSimpleName() + "], received:" + event);
    }
    
    @EventListener
    public void handleLong(AppEvent<Long> event) {
       System.out.println("Event[" + event.getClass().getSimpleName() + "], received:" + event);
    }

}
```

Comment: Without this, the event will be multicasted to irrelevant listeners, thanks for sharing this @pls.